# Which string interpolation method is faster in Rust?

Tags: rust, string-interpolation

I'm new to Rust and I wonder if any "`string-interpolation` method" is faster.

```
let var = "World";
println!("Hello {}", var);
println!("Hello {var}");
format!("{argument}", argument = "test");
```

Is there even any observable difference?

Since these macros are converted into Rust source code at `compile-time`, whereby each argument interacts with a [`formatter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html), it probably gets optimized away, right?

I wonder about `positional parameters` and `named parameters` in particular.

Comment: All templating is done at compile time. The only difference here should be that the 3rd call is not printing to stdout.

Comment: @IanRehwinkel: the third one will also allocate (albeit in release mode the whole thing will get optimised away).

Comment: `println` prints, `format` converts to a string. How should those two be compared? They do different things ...

Comment: @Finomnis Yeah they can't be compared properly. I just put it there to complement the others. But it's probably more confusing than helping..

Comment: If its just the `argument = ...` syntax you're comparing, you can do that with `println!` too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"Hello {}", var`, `"Hello {var}"` and `"Hello {argument}", argument = var` will compile to the [exact same bytecode](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Wv4dnrbxr).

Note that this is not just an optimization, this is guaranteed to be done at compile time because all three generate the same [Arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) object that gets passed on to the the internal print implementation.

```rust
pub fn foo(var: u32){
    println!("Hello {}", var);
}

pub fn bar(var: u32){
    println!("Hello {var}");
}

pub fn baz(var: u32){
    println!("Hello {argument}", argument = var);
}
```

```
example::foo:
        sub     rsp, 72
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
        lea     rax, [rsp + 4]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for u32>::fmt@GOTPCREL]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        lea     rax, [rip + .Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.2]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], 2
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 56], 0
        lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 40], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 48], 1
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 24]
        call    qword ptr [rip + std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL]
        add     rsp, 72
        ret

example::bar:
        sub     rsp, 72
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
        lea     rax, [rsp + 4]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for u32>::fmt@GOTPCREL]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        lea     rax, [rip + .Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.2]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], 2
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 56], 0
        lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 40], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 48], 1
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 24]
        call    qword ptr [rip + std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL]
        add     rsp, 72
        ret

example::baz:
        sub     rsp, 72
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
        lea     rax, [rsp + 4]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for u32>::fmt@GOTPCREL]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        lea     rax, [rip + .Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.2]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], 2
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 56], 0
        lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 40], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 48], 1
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 24]
        call    qword ptr [rip + std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL]
        add     rsp, 72
        ret

.Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.0:
        .ascii  "Hello "

.Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.1:
        .byte   10

.Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.2:
        .quad   .Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.0
        .asciz  "\006\000\000\000\000\000\000"
        .quad   .Lanon.460b7f3ee3193f887017359a1e30dfa7.1
        .asciz  "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

`format`, however, does something completely different. So comparing it in regards of performance doesn't make much sense. Although when comparing different ways of how `format` can be used, the same reasoning applies to it as well, of course.

Comment: Note that this is not just an optimization: the underlying [`Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) does not differentiate at all between the various way to specify an argument, this is all done at compile-time.